# How can I shift a li element to the right in a nav-tabs navbar using Bootstrap 5?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I searched everywhere in the web, but I couldn't find any tips on how to shift my "User information" and "Logout" li element to the right of my navbar using bootstrap.
Maybe the solution is quite simple but since I am a beginner with bootstrap it isn't easy for me.

Here is my code:

```
<!--  NAVBAR  -->
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inserisci NC</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Modifica NC</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Elimina NC</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">User information</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Logout</a>
  </li>  
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another **ul.nav.nav-tabs** inside the current **nav-tabs**. And use these two classes on it too.

- ml-auto : move it to the right
- border-0: removes its border since the outer nav-tabs has border.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inserisci NC</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Modifica NC</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Elimina NC</a>
  </li>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs ml-auto border-0">
    <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">User information</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

---

Use two **ul.nav.nav-tabs** with space in between.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between border-bottom">
  <!--  NAVBAR  -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs border-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inserisci NC</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Modifica NC</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Elimina NC</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs border-0">
    <li class="nav-item no-border">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">User information</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another nav-tabs. Assuming you're using **Bootstrap 5** as the question states, simply use `ms-auto` to push the nav-items to the right...

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inserisci NC</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Modifica NC</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Elimina NC</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ms-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">User information</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Logout</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It's important to note: Bootstrap 4 `ml-auto` has been replaced with `ms-auto` in Bootstrap 5.

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/js3VbaCSk0)